# How to measure the divergence of vectors

Tags: statistics, combinations

Here are 100 three-dimensional vectors, namely $(x_i,y_i,z_i),i=1,2,\cdots,100$, satisfying that
$$x_i+y_i+z_i=1,\quad x_i,y_i,z_i\ge0$$
for any $i$. How can I define the divergence of them?

For instance, if $x_i=y_j=z_k=1/3$ for any $i,j,k$, they are very concentrated.
But the sequence goes like $(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(0,0,1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(0,1,0)$, $(x_3,y_3,z_3)=(1,0,0), \cdots$ will be very divergent.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the maximum angle between every pair.

You could find the average angle between pairs.

You could find the maximum difference between two vectors.

You could find the average difference between two vectors.

That's not what "divergence" usually means in mathematics but I think I got your meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, maybe it should be 'distance'? BTW, could you please provide some more advanced methods?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by advanced methods.  Each of these can be done with arithmetic.  Since you don't already have a definition of what you want, maybe you could clarify in your question what your goal is, why you want this thing.